# How to make a layout invisible in Qt?

Tags: qt, layout

I add a layout in a dialog and sometimes I want it and all its containing widgets to hide. How to implement it? I try `layout->setEnable(false)`, but it doesn't seem to work in my tests.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do that. You should add a widget in your form, put children inside the widget and assign desired layout to the widget. The behavior will be generally the same, but you can use `setVisible` or `hide` methods of the widget.

Answer (score 33):

Transform QLayout to QWidget first, then you can use QWidget->hide().
[image]

Comment: While Pavel's answer is kinda correct, the "You can't do that." bit is misleading. This answer is more useful, as it shows a handy UI-diven way to achieve the desired result in a couple of clicks. You _can_ do that.

Comment: @M_M Imo, no you can't do that. You can't call hide on the layout. You need to convert the layout to a widget, exactly what Pavel's answer says. This answer does not provide extra info. Who cares about the GUI.

Comment: @Swedgin: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Who cares about the GUI". This is about QLayout and QWidget - those are both GUI elements, so I think probably everyone who reads this question cares about the GUI, and at least the 23+ people who upvoted this answer...
Also, just realised that maybe you meant who cares about a GUI-driven way to solve the OP's question. Same answer - at least 23 people.